# Keyup dentro de un jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, input

Estoy creando un carrito de compras, y necesito un poquito de ayuda u orientación. Tengo un jQuery DataTable y en la parte de cantidad, agregue una función keyup para saber el total a pagar por producto solicitado. El asunto es que funciona, pero cuando agrego más de 1 producto al datatables, los valores se vuelven crazy (loco), y solo funciona la primera fila con el keyup, pero el valor del producto cambia al de la segunda fila, NO a la fila que corresponde. ¿Cómo podría hacer que el keyup funcione en todas las filas donde corresponde? [Imagen con problemas al tener 2 registros en el datatables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BysAQ.png)

[image: Imagen datatables con problemas con mas de 1 registro]

```
//
$(document).ready( function(){
    tablaProductoCarritoMujer = $('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer').DataTable({
        "language": {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "No existen Productos Agregados al Carrito",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero ",
                    "sLast":     " Último",
                    "sNext":     " Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior "
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
        responsive: "true",
        dom: "Bfrtilp",
        "columnDefs":[{
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        //Acá le colocamos los botones, editar y borrar.
        //Colocamos esto ``, para que no haya problemas con las comillas.
        "defaultContent": 
            `<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'>                               
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btnBorrarProductoCarrito'>ELIMINAR</button>
                </div>
             </div>`
        }],     
    });
});
//Función para Obtener el valor de los datos de la sección de imágenes.
var precioP;
//Esta es una función onclick que utilicé para obtener los valores del producto.
function carritoCompras(id_producto, nombreProducto,stockActual, precioProductoTotal,imgProducto, precioProducto, envio){

//var lg = [id_producto, nombreProducto, stockActual, precioProductoTotal, imgProducto, precioProducto, envio];
//console.log(lg[0], lg[2], lg[3]);
//Agregamos los datos nuevos al DataTables.
//contarCantidad(id_producto,stockActual, precioProducto);
    Swal.fire({
        title: "¡Producto Agregado al Carrito de Compras!",
        icon: 'success',
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000,
    });

    //En esta parte agrego una fila a mi tabla.
    tablaProductoCarritoMujer.row.add([id_producto,nombreProducto,'<img src="'+imgProducto+'" width="50">',precioProducto,'<input type="number" name="carritoProducto" id="carritoProducto" class="text-center" value="" style="width: 50%;" required="true">','<input type="number" name="precioTotal" id="precioTotal" class="text-center" style="width: 70%;" readonly="true">'])
    .draw();

    //console.log(tablaProductoCarritoMujer[0]);
    var trElement = $('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer').find('td.sorting_1');
    var resultado = "";
    for(i=0; i < trElement.length; i++){ //Recorre las filas 1 a 1
        var celdas = $(trElement[i]);//devolverá las celdas de una fila
        codigo = $(celdas[0]).text();//Me devuelve el valor del id del segundo Producto.
        //console.log(codigo);
    }
    //Funcionando, el input muestre el valor actual de los productos agregados. 
    var filas = [$('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer').find('tbody tr').length];
    if (filas > 0) {
        for(let i =0; i < filas.length; i++){
            let resultado = filas[i];
            let valorInput = parseInt(resultado);
            $('#txtProductosAdquiridos').val(valorInput);
            //$('.precioTotal').val(valorInput);
        }
    }
    //console.log(array); 
    //Borrar una fila de Productos, funcionando correctamente.
    $('.btnBorrarProductoCarrito').on('click', function(){
        //Nos dirigimos al tr de nuestra tabla.
        //this, hace referencia al atributo fila creado arriba.
        fila = $(this).closest('tr');
        //Para Borrar la fila.
        if (tablaProductoCarritoMujer.row(fila).remove(fila).draw(true)) {
            //Funcionando, el input muestre el valor actual de los productos agregados.
            var filas = [$('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer td.sorting_1').length];
            for(let i =0; i < filas.length; i++){
                var resultado = filas[i];
                var valorInput = parseInt(resultado);
                $('#txtProductosAdquiridos').val(valorInput);
            }
        }
    });
    
    //Agrego clases a cada td.
    var row = $("#tablaProductoCarritoMujer tbody td");
    $('td',row)
    //Acá le agruegé la clase.
    console.log($(row).addClass("cantidad"));
    //Agrego id a cada td. 
    var row = $("#tablaProductoCarritoMujer tbody td");
    $.each(row, function(i, td) {
      if (!$(td).attr('id')) {    
            $(td).attr('id', i+1);
        }
    });
    //Función keyup para mostrar el total por producto.
    $('#carritoProducto').keyup(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Cantidad Ingresada.
        let cantidad = $(this).val();
        console.log(cantidad);
        let total = precioProducto * cantidad;
        //$('#precioTotal').val(total), esto corresponde al input de la imagen 
       //del th TOTAL, eso debiese aparecer. 
        let precioTotal = $('#precioTotal').val(total);
    });
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar un fragmento de código donde se entienda quien es `carritoProducto` y quien es `precioTotal`?

Comment: ok, amigo, lo hago altiro, lo que sucede, no lo hice por que es mucho código, pero agregare más código.

Comment: Si quería ver esa parte para confirmar lo que pensaba. Tienes IDs que se repiten N veces en el DOM `carritoProducto` y `precioTotal`

Comment: como lo puedo solucionar amigo, que me recomienda??, llevo días pegado en eso XD

Comment: Ricardo Campos Villarroel, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, agradecido y me funciono todo correctamente, una vez más, gracias..

Comment: _El atributo global id define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento._ [mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id) esto es parte de lo que te indicaba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución podría ser la siguiente, a los input **carritoProducto** (que segun entiendo es el dato cantidad de productos) agrégales una clase al momento de añadirlos a la tabla. Por el ejemplo el nombre de la clase seria `cantidad_productos`.

```
<input type="number" name="carritoProducto" id="carritoProducto" class="cantidad_productos text-center" value="" style="width: 50%;" required="true" data-precio-producto="'+precioProducto+'">
```

Como aspecto adicional incorpora el precio del producto ya que es un dato que vamos a utilizar mas adelante (para esto debes agregar el atributo `data-"nombre de la variable"`, en este caso seria `data-precio-producto`, mayor información sobre los [atributos de datos (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) y [manipulación de dataset con jquery](https://api.jquery.com/data/)).

Tambien incluye una clase al input **precioTotal** (en este caso el nombre seria `total_productos`)

```
<input type="number" name="precioTotal" id="precioTotal" class="text-center total_productos" style="width: 70%;" readonly="true">
```

Dentro del `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` agrega lo siguiente:

```
$('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer').on('keyup','.cantidad_productos', function(){
    var precio_p = $(this).data('precio-producto') // obtenemos el valor asignado en el atributo data-precio-producto
    var cantidad = $(this).val() //obtenemos el valor propio del input
    var input_total = $(this).closest('tr').find('.total_productos'); //con closest obtenemos el padre mas cercano tipo 'tr' y buscamos dentro de el input con la clase .total_productos
    var total = precio_p * cantidad; //calculamos
    input_total.val(total); //asignamos el valor
});
```

Con esto configuramos el evento keyup de los input independientes si son o no preexistentes en el DOM.

Comment: Te sugiero que para el botón eliminar hagas una lógica parecida. Seria algo asi `$('#tablaProductoCarritoMujer').on('click','.eliminar_productos', function(){ ... });`

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Puedes mejorarla si agregas enlace a documentación sobre temas interesantes, por ejemplo: [atributos de datos (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), será de utilidad para el autor de la pregunta y para visitantes con problemas similares. +1